Set QTableView cell size when using fetch more?
I can set the size of my table rows using the following code:
    table = QTableView()
    table.setModel(CustomModel(dataFrame))
    table.resizeRowsToContents()

My CustomModel.data() function returns a size when role is Qt.SizeHintRole:
class CustomModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    [...]

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role=Qt.ItemDataRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        
        path = self._dataframe.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
        pixmap = QPixmap(path)
        if role == Qt.SizeHintRole:
           return pixmap.size()

But when I modify my model so that it can fetch more items, as in the official example, the size is not taken into account anymore:
def setDataFrame(self, dataFrame: pd.DataFrame):
    self._dataframe = dataFrame
    self.beginResetModel()
    self._rowCount = 0
    self.endResetModel()
    return

def canFetchMore(self, parent=QModelIndex()) -> bool:
    return False if parent.isValid() else self._rowCount < len(self._dataframe)

def fetchMore(self, parent: QModelIndex | QPersistentModelIndex) -> None:
    if parent.isValid(): return

    remainder = len(self._dataframe) - self._rowCount
    itemsToFetch = min(100, remainder)

    if itemsToFetch <= 0: return

    self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), self._rowCount, self._rowCount + itemsToFetch - 1)
    self._rowCount += itemsToFetch
    self.endInsertRows()

def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()) -> int:
    return self._rowCount if parent == QModelIndex() else 0

When I change rowCount() so that it always returns len(self._dataframe), the size works again (but the "fetch more" feature breaks):
def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()) -> int:
    return len(self._dataframe) if parent == QModelIndex() else 0

Any idea why this happens?

Please include a comprehensive [mre].

@arthur Do a preliminary research. The reference on the resizeRowsToContents() says it resizes all rows(implying it works on current rows), not that it will resize for all rows added in the future.

As relent95 reports, the action only takes effect on the currently existing rows. If you want to update that as soon as contents are added either call it again on model updates (for instance, by connecting to rowsInserted), or eventually set the vertical header resize mode. Still, if you want further help (in case the above didn't suffice), do as suggested and provide a proper MRE, as the short excerpt above from the class data() is insufficient (and inadequate).

Thank you very much, you answered my question! The problem was indeed that resizeRowsToContents() does not resize rows in the future. So table.model().rowsInserted.connect(lambda: self.content.resizeRowsToContents()) works perfectly fine. I surely should have tried this, but it was not obvious to me. I can answer my question, or you can do it if you prefer.

And indeed, my question was not complete and correct, I should have make it more clear.

@arthur.sw remember to use @username when replying to someone and more than one user participates in the comment section.

@musicamante I think you both answered my question.

As @musicamante and @relent95 explained, resizeRowsToContents() does not resize rows in the future ; so I have to call it whenever a new row is instered.
Adding table.model().rowsInserted.connect(lambda: self.content.resizeRowsToContents()) solved my problem.
